# Python: How to keep running program until some value becomes 0 and checking how long it takes

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
time_counter = 0
for i in range(time_counter):
    if pred > 0:
        prey, pred = prey*(1+A-B*pred), pred*1-C+D*prey)
    else:
        print time_counter
    time_counter +=1
```

The values for A, B, C, and D are fixed to 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.00009. pred is 20 and prey is 1000. I'm trying to figure out how long it takes for pred to become 0 (as an integer, not float) and then display that time.

Logically, I can think of it is starting the time at 0 and running the formula...if pred is greater than 0 than repeat and until pred is 0 or less than 0 to stop and display the time. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Please try to keep it basic. I'd like to be able to do it using a for loop with conditional statements and using Python 2.7 syntax.

EDIT: Sorry if something was confusing. I want to count the time periods (which in this case would be the number of iterations) that the loop runs until pred is equal to 0. However, pred should be considered 0 once it is < 1 so even 0.999 would be 0.

Comment: Use a `while` loop, `for` iterates a collection.

Comment: Look into the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial).

Comment: You need time or number of iterations?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sloppy answer from my mobile:

```
import time

time.time()
while (pred > 0):
    # smooth jazz
time.time()
```

Apologies if this kind of answer is a bit lacking as I don't have an IDE available to verify my syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a while loop. Your for loop wont even start if you set `time_counter = 0`

```
time_counter = 0
while pred > 0:
    prey, pred = int(prey*(1+A-B*pred)), int(pred*(1-C+D*prey))
    time_counter +=1
print time_counter
```

This will run until `pred <= 0`. Although it will not time the function, but rather count the number of loops it takes for `pred` to be `<= 0`

Comment: When I tried this, it gives me something like 6807 time periods which doesn't seem right. If I print the output of pred, it's returning float numbers when I want it truncated.

Comment: as I and many others have asked, do you want this timed or do you want to count iterations? Do you mean it should take 39 loops for pred to be less than 0?

Comment: Yeah, I want to count the iterations as every iteration = 1 time period in this instance. The issue I am having is the program is taking all the numbers to be floats since A, B, C, D are floats so it will consider something like 1.0000000001 to be greater than 0 when I want it to be just 1.

Comment: Try it now, it will convert the answers to ints

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the while loop worked however I needed to add int tags before the formulas ran in order for it to appropriately evaluate. Otherwise I was getting into very miniscule values that were greater than 0 (think 1*10^-9) and the program would just end once it couldn't handle the small values.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I would do:

```
time_counter = 0
while pred > 0:
    prey, pred = prey*(1+A-B*pred), pred*(1-C+D*prey)
    print prey, pred
    time_counter +=1
    print time_counter
```